# How to add div next to <ul> in bootstrap-vue dropdown-toggle?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap-vue library, and I am using  component to generate dropdown. However i need to add additional button. This button need to be located right after  in DOM, but i have not found a way how to make it possible. If i write this button just inside  component, it is not generated at all, and if i write button outside of , it is not generated after . Is there any way to generate my button right after  by using v-slot or something else?

Comment: Might be easier to help if you add your current code to the question.

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? We really need to see some code in order to know exactly what you're talking about.